# How to use sub domain using angular js and html5?

Tags: angularjs

I am building a site ,which requires a unique sub-domain for each profile. The technology which I am using angularjs and html5. example:-www.xyz.com,hemant.xyz.com,ravi.xyz.com

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: So what is your concern?

Comment: I would never use the URL to determine what profile gets loaded, I would always do it based on the logged in user. So you would need to store somewhere which sub-domain each user is associated with. Now if your sub domains are companies for example, then it should be part of you domain that users exist in companies.

Comment: In addition, I am referring to a web application. If it is just a marketing site then by all means.

Comment: but client requirement on angularjs and html5 only.